# HTML5 tag not working in IE9/10

Tags: html5-canvas

I have simple canvas tag and trying to use it as graph plotting area for my project. Below is the code.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
</head>
<body>
    <canvas id="canvas" width="1600" height="160" style="background-image: url(ecg_back.png); style="background-color: black;"></canvas>
    <script type='text/javascript'>

         var canvas = document.getElementById("canvas");
        var ctx = canvas.getContext("2d");
        ctx.fillStyle = "#dbbd7a";
        ctx.fill();

        var fps = 60;
        var n = 1;


        var data = [
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 20, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82,
            148, 149, 149, 150, 150, 150, 143, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82, 82];


        drawWave();

        function drawWave() {
            setTimeout(function() {
                requestAnimationFrame(drawWave);
                ctx.lineWidth = "1";
                ctx.strokeStyle = 'green';

                // Drawing code goes here
                n += 1;
                if (n >= data.length) {
                    n = 1;
                }
                ctx.beginPath();
                ctx.moveTo(n - 1, data[n - 1]);
                ctx.lineTo(n, data[n]);
                ctx.stroke();

                ctx.clearRect(n+1, 0, 10, canvas.height);

            }, 1000 / fps);
        }


    </script>
</body>
```

This is working as expected in Firefox and Chrome but not in any version of IE. Is it like we can never use canvas tag in IE or i have written something wrong?

Early response would be appreciated.

Comment: Try to move the `drawWave();` function call after the function is implemented (under the function implementation). Does IE javascript console show you any errors?

Comment: moved the function call, still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

IE9 does not have requestAnimationFrame built-in.

You can add that capability using a polyfill.  Here's and excellent shim from Paul Irish:

https://gist.github.com/paulirish/1579671

Just put this polyfill above the rest of your code:

```
// http://paulirish.com/2011/requestanimationframe-for-smart-animating/
// http://my.opera.com/emoller/blog/2011/12/20/requestanimationframe-for-smart-er-animating
// requestAnimationFrame polyfill by Erik Möller. fixes from Paul Irish and Tino Zijdel
// MIT license

(function() {
    var lastTime = 0;
    var vendors = ['ms', 'moz', 'webkit', 'o'];
    for(var x = 0; x < vendors.length && !window.requestAnimationFrame; ++x) {
        window.requestAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'RequestAnimationFrame'];
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = window[vendors[x]+'CancelAnimationFrame'] 
                                   || window[vendors[x]+'CancelRequestAnimationFrame'];
    }

    if (!window.requestAnimationFrame)
        window.requestAnimationFrame = function(callback, element) {
            var currTime = new Date().getTime();
            var timeToCall = Math.max(0, 16 - (currTime - lastTime));
            var id = window.setTimeout(function() { callback(currTime + timeToCall); }, 
              timeToCall);
            lastTime = currTime + timeToCall;
            return id;
        };

    if (!window.cancelAnimationFrame)
        window.cancelAnimationFrame = function(id) {
            clearTimeout(id);
        };
}());
```

IE10 should work fine for you.  Your example works fine for me in IE10 emulation mode.

Good luck with your project!

Comment: you are right @markE, but my target browser is IE9. in the link you mentioned, there is so many piece of code which made me more confused to go with which. Please can you give some code snippets? sorry for asking more!

Comment: No problem.  I added Paul Irish's polyfill code to my answer.  Just put that polyfill code above your code and IE9 will have requestAnimationFrame.  Cheers!